# is there a Windows Forms control that will allow the user to select multiple folders?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried both the `OpenFileDialog` and the `FolderBrowserDialog` controls and the first one does not allow me to select folders while the second one allows me to select only 1 folder.

Any other controls that will do what I want or will I need to create my own?

Comment: Create your own, I think. (That's what Dropbox had to do.)

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576769/required-dialog-for-selecting-multiple-files-and-folders-net)

Comment: FolderBrowserDialog does not allow multiple folders to be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FolderBrowserDialog only allows to select one folder. Try this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4472/Enhanced-BrowseForFolder-styled-TreeView

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look at these references:

1. [Browse Multiple folders using FolderBrowserDialog in windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261598/browse-multiple-folders-using-folderbrowserdialog-in-windows-application)
2. [C# - How to customize OpenFileDialog to select multiple folders and files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628021/c-sharp-how-to-customize-openfiledialog-to-select-multiple-folders-and-files)

Hope this will help you.