# Alternative to Ookii Dialogs in WPF to select multiple folder?

Tags: wpf, ookii

Does anyone know of an alternative to Ookii Dialogs in WPF that allow to select multiple folders at once?
I think I've seen one, but I can't find anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48824688/1177147). Reverts back to single-select for anything earlier than Vista, though i.e. XP, NT, 98, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Ookii Dialogs, but I know that `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonOpenFileDialog` should work if you set `IsFolderPicker = true` and `Multiselect = true`. It's part of the Microsoft-issued `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell` NuGet package, which you can find here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/

```
var d = new Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonOpenFileDialog { IsFolderPicker = true, Multiselect = true };
d.ShowDialog();
var selectedFolders = d.FileNames;
```