# OpenFolderDialog multiselect in Avalonia

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

Example code where `OpenFileDialog` saves selected directory to list:

```cs
OpenFolderDialog dialog = new OpenFolderDialog();
var result = await dialog.ShowAsync(this);
ListOfDirectories.Add(result);
```

But the problem is that user might want to select two, or three, or any other amount of directories. With this implementation user has to do this in loop. `OpenFileDialog` does not support multiselection directly.

There is also `OpenFileDialog` which has multiselect property, but as name suggests its for files, I need it only for folders.

Currently I do not have any ideas how to bypass this problem.

Comment: As Avalonia wraps over native system dialogs and those native dialogs might not support multiple selection of folders (like the Windows one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261598/browse-multiple-folders-using-folderbrowserdialog-in-windows-application) you won't easily get this feature without using your own dialogs.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for reply. Thats a little problematic but with some luck someone might already did it.